# How to convert XSD to a Java class?

Tags: java, android, xsd, wsdl

I have an [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) file which is derived from a WSDL, and I need to generate a Java class for use in my Android app. How can I do that? Are there any examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

User [Simple Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). Its tried and tested on Android platform. [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-xml-binding-simple-tutorial.html) is sample tutorial.

Comment: That will not work. Simple will bind XML using annotations in Java objects, it does not generate Java objects from the XSD, as the op desires.